# Unable to ping between two devices in two subnets connected via router

Tags: ping, subnet

I have two systems running on Windows, the first one S1 in subnet 192.168.3.0 and the second one S2 in subnet 192.168.2.0. Both are connected to my Linux box, say R1, which I want to act as router for pinging between these Windows systems.
S1 is connected via eth0 NIC of R1 and S2 is connected via eth2 NIC of R1 as below:

[image: Setup]

Following are the configs of NIC's of R1:

- IP address of eth0 of R1- 192.168.3.6
- IP address of eth2 of R1- 192.168.2.8.

The IP address of eth0 of R1, i.e., 192.168.3.6 is assigned as the default gateway in Windows S1 as shown in figure below

[image: Network Configuration of S1]

The IP address of eth2 of R1 i.e., 192.168.2.8 is assigned as the default gateway in Windows S2 as shown in figure below:

[image: Network Configuration of S2]

I aim to ping S1 from S2 and vice versa, and it is not working. However, ping from S1 to R1 & S2 to R1 is fine

Below is the routing table in my router R1.

[image: Routing table in R1]

Please assist me if any configuration is further required.

Comment: What is the Vendor of the Router?

Comment: this is an imx6 board with yocto linux framework

Comment: On both Windows computers, is the Windows Firewall enabled? If so, is **File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)** enabled for the active firewall profile? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: Hi [joeqwerty](https://serverfault.com/users/19152/joeqwerty),


This option is already enabled in my system, still it is not working. However ping from S1 to R1 and S2 to R2 is working

Answer (score 1):

Check out the /etc/sysctl.conf file of your Linux box. Is there this string net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 there? Add one if no and reboot then.

Comment: Yes the option is already set to 1 in sysctl.conf ; still the ping is not working. Anything to do other than this to configure the box as router?

Comment: @paravozik you used the answers as a comment. please fix this